# Gradle - build jar which includes both .class and .java files?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using android studio + gradle. I have a module that is a plain standalone java app. Is there a way I can package that module into a .jar file that includes both its compiled .class files, and its source .java files? By default it looks like android studio is only including .class files for me.

I was originally doing this using Eclipse (export as a jar), but can't figure out how to do the equivalent with android studio.

---- EDIT -----

This is my current build.gradle file, but it still outputs a jar that only includes the .class files:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is most common to publish a separate sources JAR from compiled classes.

To do that in Gradle, add this to your Gradle build:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

Comment: What would I replace 'android' with in the 'from' line if it's just a plain java module?

Comment: @user3203425, with nothing. Just remove `android` and leave `sourceSets` there.

Comment: @Opal I've updated my build.gradle, but the jar still only contains the .class files, any ideas?

Comment: @user3203425 Do you see the -sources.jar file? That should have .java files and not .class files.

Comment: @EricWendelin - ah ok I had to run gradlew sourcesJar - ok so now I see -sources.jar which has the java files in it. But it does not have the .class files in it.